# Perforce - create workspace from Windows cmd

Tags: perforce

I need to create a p4 workspace (client) from windows cmd. I also want to edit the view (what and where to be synced), as well as to alter some options (like clobber, rmdir, etc).
Can you please help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: have you read the p4 command reference for `p4 workspace`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all of this with the p4.exe command line utility. By default it is is installed to C:\Program Files\Perforce\

Open the CMD prompt and navigate to the aforementioned directory.

First you'll do:

```
p4.exe login
```

Then:

```
p4.exe client
```

and configure your client spec including any options like clobber, rmdir, etc.

Finally, you can call p4.exe sync, once the client spec has been setup correctly.

Alternatively, you could use P4V if you do not *need* the command line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I already know that, but need the exact commands to edit the client.

Comment: When I type in cmd:
p4 -p ***  client test_client
a file opens up with the client specifications.

Comment: As you say, the client spec opens up in an editor.  This isn't some sort of devious trick.  :) Use the editor to edit the file, then save the file and close the editor.

Answer (score 0):

To edit your client workspace view you first use the 'p4 client' command as follows:

```
p4 client myclient
```

where 'myclient' is the name of the Perforce workspace. Whatever your default P4EDITOR is set to, which usually in Windows is Notepad, the client spec opens and you can modify your options within your Windows editor.

An example is here in the User Guide under 'Refining workspace views':

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.configuration.html#DB5-54093

I hope this has been helpful. Let me know if you have any other questions.

REFERENCES

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/How-to-Script-Client-Workspace-Cloning

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! This works great, but what I need is to create and edit the workspace entirely with cmd commands.
I have another question-what does the client template look like, is it in text format, what should it contain.

Comment: You're welcome. If you run 'p4 client -o' it will show all the fields. Or look here http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_client.html  Yes you can use scripting to update and create the client via the command line just like that article I sent you shows using sed. And yes, the client spec is in text format.

Answer (score 0):

A few years too late , but in case others run into my situation:

I had to create workspaces for a team of users which all had to be locally identical (same root, view, stream etc)

I created a template workspace with p4V, set things as desired.
then used a .bat file to invoke  `p4 client` with various flags to pass the template.

.bat file contents:

```
:: user must log in to perforce as admin
echo USERNAME = %USERNAME%
echo Login to perforce:

p4 login

SET LOCAL_ROOT=C:\project
SET TEMPLATE=template_workspace
SET STREAM_NAME=//depot/stream

echo create local dir..
mkDir %LOCAL_ROOT%
echo create local workspace...
p4 -d %LOCAL_ROOT% client -o -t %TEMPLATE% %USERNAME%_project | p4 client -i
echo set stream ...
p4 client -f -s -S %STEAM_NAME% %USERNAME%_animation-pipeline
```

possibly you could copy the output  of `p4 client`, edit and save the client spec to a text file, then pipe it to p4 client

```
type client_spec.txt | p4 client -i
```

the fact that you have be this indirect is silly. We should be able to invoke `p4 client` with flags & values and be done.